# I am getting this error "No module: ngResource"

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Trying to use the Angular $resource, and its coming back as not a method. Looking through the sparse documentation, I was able to find this :

```
angular.module('productServices', ['ngResource']).
```

That you're supposed to include it in your app module. Fair enough, I throw it in and get :

```
Uncaught Error: No module: ngResource
```

Hmm.. does this not come with Angular.js and its a separate plugin?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

It's a separate file that you'll need to include in your project, as of version 1.0.0rc3 ([see changelog on GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#100rc3-barefoot-telepathy-2012-03-29)).

Head over to http://code.angularjs.org -- under the folder for any version after this release, you should see the `angular-resource.js` file available for download and inclusion in your project.

Comment: @Trip Sure thing; I've updated my answer to include instructions on where to find `angular-resource.js`.

Comment: Sadly, the resource I need DOES exist locally, and yet I'm still getting the error.  I'm just trying to get my foot in the door here, with the tutorial at https://ccoenraets.github.io/ionic-tutorial/create-angular-controller.html ... and character for character done as instructed, it fails for me on that page, with:

Module 'ngResource' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it.  I'll keep poking at it.

Comment: @JoshuaEricTurcotte Perhaps you're missing the dependency to angular resource in your karma.conf.js.