# Invoking RESTFul services with ANGULARJS

Tags: rest, angularjs

When I am trying to include the service in my web application I get an error in the angular-resource.js perfmite not load the file file. The error is: "Uncaught TypeError: Can not call method '$ $ minErr' of undefined".

Any idea?

Thank you very much.

Hello,

I have in my html code including:

```
<script src="angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="angular.js"></script>
```

In the configuration file app I have the next code:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource','ngI18n','directives']);
```

When the framework start to compile this code is when I try error is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Can not call method '$ $ minErr' of undefined
```

I don't understand why this problem...

Thanks

Comment: You might want to use https://github.com/mgonto/restangular instead of regular angular to consume RESTful resources.

Comment: Without more information (like code to reproduce), there is really no help to offer.

Answer (score 1):

You are including angular javascript files wrong.
First include angular, and only then, angular-resource.
Like this:

```
<script src="angular.js"></script> 
<script src="angular-resource.js"></script>
```

EDIT:
Take a look at this [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/lh26sbAduazkxdkIZKRU?p=preview)

Hopefully it will help you get started. The $resource is successfully injected.

Comment: I change the order but I have the same problem or similar.
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method '$$minErr'
Uncaught Error: No module: ngResource

Comment: That's another problem.
Can you create a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/) that illustrates the problem?
And please, make sure you always put angular.js before the other angular javascript files.

Comment: looks you are running into this problem [No module: ngResource](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14631749/i-am-getting-this-error-no-module-ngresource) are you sure the angular-resources.js is accessible? What version are you using?

Comment: I use the version 1.2.0. I am going to create a plunker app...